# NHibernate Mapping Exception: An association from the table dbo.AccountGroup refers to an unmapped class: System.String

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am getting this error:

An association from the table dbo.AccountGroup refers to an unmapped class: System.String

This is my entity:

```
public class AccountGroup
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    public AccountGroup()
    {
        this.Accounts = new List<Account>();
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual int Category { get; set; }
    public virtual AccountGroup Group { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<LedgerEntry> LedgerEntries { get; set; }

    public Account()
    {
        this.LedgerEntries = new List<LedgerEntry>();
    }
}
```

This is my mapping:

```
    public AccountGroupMap()
    {
        Table("dbo.AccountGroup");
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("Id");
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.Parent)
            .Column("Parent");
        Map(x => x.Description);
        HasMany(x => x.Accounts)
            .KeyColumn("GroupId")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

    public AccountMap()
    {
        Table("dbo.Account");
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("Id");
        Map(x => x.Code);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.Category);
        References(x => x.Group)
            .Column("AccountGroupId");
        HasMany(x => x.LedgerEntries)
            .KeyColumn("AccountId")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
```

Here are my tables:

CREATE TABLE AccountGroup
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(20),
    Parent int,
    Description varchar(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Account
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Code varchar(30),
    Name varchar(20),
    Description varchar(20),
    Category int,
    AccountGroupId int,
    FOREIGN KEY (AccountGroupId) REFERENCES AccountGroup (Id)
)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have

```
References(x => x.Parent)
        .Column("Parent");
```

When Parent is defined as

```
public virtual string Parent { get; set; }
```

You can't reference a string (unless it's a collection element)

Comment: Thanks... I had the exact same problem.  Wish I could vote more than once :)